# Duplicate method 'ProcessRequest' in ASPX

Tags: asp.net-mvc, f#

I'm trying to code ASP.NET MVC views (WebForms view engine) in F#. I can already write regular ASP.NET WebForms ASPX and it works ok, e.g.

```
<%@ Page Language="F#" %>
<%
for i in 1..2 do %>
<%=sprintf "%d" i %>
```

so I assume I have everything in my web.config correctly set up.

However, when I make the page inherit from ViewPage:

```
<%@ Page Language="F#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
```

I get this error:

> Compiler Error Message: FS0442:
>   Duplicate method. The abstract method
>   'ProcessRequest' has the same name and
>   signature as an abstract method in an
>   inherited type.

The problem seems to be this piece of code generated by the F# CodeDom provider:

```
[<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute>]
abstract ProcessRequest : System.Web.HttpContext -> unit
[<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute>]
default this.ProcessRequest  (context:System.Web.HttpContext) =
    let mutable context = context
    base.ProcessRequest(context) |> ignore
```

when I change the Page directive to use C# instead, the generated code is:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
public new virtual void ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext context) {
    base.ProcessRequest(context);
}
```

which of course works fine and AFAIK is not semantically the same as the generated F# code.

I'm using .NET 4.0.30319.1 (RTM) and MVC 2 RTM

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I'm not sure if there is any way to declare a `new virtual` member in F#.  A quick look through the spec didn't turn up anything promising...